# How do I write a SUMIF formula for pricing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, range

[image: SAMPLE IMAGE HERE]

I have an excel program used to price out paint and the "tints" used in the paint formula. What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. If the sum of cells B54:H54 is =0 then cell I54=0
2. If the sum of cells B54:H54 has a range of 1 to 30 then I54=30 as in a (30 tint     min rule unless there is 0 tints then =0)
3. If the sum of cells B54:H54 exceeds 30 then it's whatever the value comes out to.
   After looking online I assume I need to use the SUMIF function, I'm just not certain on how to setup the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUMIF` is useful for conditional addition (e.g. sum only numbers which are less then 10), you need to use `SUM` and `IF`:

`=IF(SUM(B54:H54)=0,0,IF(SUM(B54:H54)<30,30,SUM(B54:H54)))`

Comment: That is absolutely PERFECT!  Thank you very much for the quick response. This working example helps me understand how I can edit my other working forms.